# Re-size UIWebView after displaying UIToolBar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've got a ViewController with a UIToolBar at the top and a UIWebView underneath. The WebView fills the entire remaining portion of the View and is set to stretch, being anchored at the top and left.

The content of the webpage is 3-4 screens long, but when I scroll down through the WebView, I can see it all. However, if I dynamically hide the UIToolBar, then re-show it again, the WebView ends up being "too big" -- it's actually longer than the space available in the ViewController, so now when I scroll through my 4 pages of content, I get to the bottom and it tends to "bounce back" and won't display the bottom half inch of web content.

Is there a way to re-size the webview after hiding the UIToolBar?

Comment: just set a new frame!? Perhaps we need some screenshot to understand it.. But if you're talking about the inner scrollview of the webview.. NO - you don't control the content size on your own. You could try to refresh it, but that's probably not needed.

Comment: Content isn't the problem... it's the webview itself is outside the bounds of the parent view, so the bottom portion of the content is under the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`webView.frame = self.view.frame`

after the hiding of the nav bar should do the trick.  also try

`webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;`

to try to eliminate bouncing if it is having an undesirable effect. Cheers!

Comment: I spoke too soon... it actually doesn't work. See, the webview already seems to re-size when the toolbar gets hidden. The problem is when the toolbar comes back, it doesn't resize. So in this case, `webView.frame = self.view.frame` causes the toolbar to be overlapped by the webview.

Comment: so pull down the frame(CGRect wFrame = self.view.frame), then set the wFrame.origin.y to be the toolbar.frame.origin.y + toolbar.frame.size.height then set the webView.frame to the wFrame when the toolbar reappears.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the webview isn't really necessary. You should instead play around with the auto resizing masks, like so:

```
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
```